# Ways to Install and uninstall programs in deb format

Tags: 11.10, installation

What are ways to install/uninstall programs in Ubuntu. I will mention only **.deb** since it is the official package format and for example installing a .sh or .run program can typically be as simple as (In latest Ubuntu) `./program.sh` or `sh program.run`.

Also note that am talking about HOW to install packages IN Ubuntu, not talking about downloading a new installer (Like some Super Cow Software Center Duke Nukem version from sourceforge or something). Only tools that already come in the repositories (In any of the 4 standard ones, main, universe, restricted or multiverse).

Take into consideration all GUI and terminal ways of doing it, with basic format of doing the installation. With this in mind I am talking for example about Software Center, synaptic, apt-get, aptitude, dpkg, etc... a way to show all tools that are available in Ubuntu to install deb packages.

NOTE - Forgot, this should be Community Wiki since it will have all ways a user can install/uninstall something. Like a friendly guide on doing that.

UPDATED question to remove the confusion some are having about sh/run files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ways to Install & Uninstall .deb packages in Ubuntu:

## SOFTWARE CENTER

This is the default GUI installer/uninstaller for Ubuntu to search, install and remove applications.

[image]

## SYNAPTIC

This was the old way which can still be used by installing the `synaptic` package. It works similar to Software Center with a few differences like installing multiple packages at the same time and other details..

[image]

## APT-GET & APT-CACHE

This are the default terminal ways in Ubuntu to search, install, update and remove applications.

[image: Searching & Installing]
Search & Install

[image]
Remove an application

[image]
Remove an application COMPLETELY (Including config files)

[image]
Update Repositories

## APTITUDE

This was the old terminal way of searching, installing, updating and removing applications. Can be used by installing the `aptitude` package.

[image]
Search & Install

[image]
Remove an application

[image]
Remove an application COMPLETELY (Including config files)

[image]
Update Repositories

## DPKG

[image]
Installing a package

[image]
Removing a package

[image]
Purging a package

There are other cases like **dselect**, **PackageKit** and **GDebi**. For Kubuntu you have alternatives like Kubuntu's **Adept Manager**, newer **KPackageKit** or **Muon**.

As an alternative to DEB packages you have **alien** which can installed RPM packages (Not to be confused with Revolutions Per Minute since that would make Fedora really fast ;) )

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused about this question. Ubuntu has its software sources, which are trusted, and comes with reliable/tested software. By passing this concept comes with security issue's. We have to teach the "Ubuntu-way", the software sources are the Achilles heel of Ubuntu. Only very experienced users know their way in the world wide(wild) web, outside the off. software sources. (Via Sourceforge, etc.)
Some dev's put a nice uninstall how to/in their software readme. (When you are lucky) But sometimes tar.gz's comes with no uninstall readme at all.
Lets not make it fancy or "interesting" to install software outside the off. sources. If I didn't understood your input and question Luis Alverdo forgive me.......

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

.run and .sh can do what they like in your system, and there is no way to have any automatic uninstall for them. This is why you should always recommend that users use .deb-files, or if they compile themselves, use checkinstall to create a deb before installing it. That way it can easily be removed afterwards.

For .run and .sh-installers, you'll just have to consult the softwares manual.

Comment: Updated question. Removed the run/sh formats.